# usb debag zenfone 4

Tags: eclipse, file, emulation

I just downloaded the plugin USB phone to use it as Zenfone4 ​​emulator Eclipse , but inside there is no .exe file for THE INSTALLATION but only with a folder inside " MTP " and " tethering " .
How do I install it and use it as an emulator ? : /

Comment: Don't advertise your other questions.

Comment: it is impossible to get an answer ... there are too many < . <

Comment: then make your question better. don't spam the rest of the site. good questions get answered.